# tensorflow simple logistic regression

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, tensorflow, logistic-regression

*Hello*

I just want to try binary classification with simple logistic regression.I've got unlabeled output data as  {1,0} // (He/she passed exam or not)
cost function returns (NaN).What is wrong?

```
learning_rate = 0.05
total_iterator = 1500
display_per = 100

data = numpy.loadtxt("ex2data1.txt",dtype=numpy.float32,delimiter=",");

training_X = numpy.asarray(data[:,[0,1]]) # 100 x 2
```

training_X contains 100 x 2 matrix as the exam scores.e.g [98.771 4.817]

```
training_Y = numpy.asarray(data[:,[2]],dtype=numpy.int) # 100 x 1
```

training_Y contains 100x1 array as, [1] [0] [0] [1] *i can't write line by line due to stackoverflow format*

```
m = data.shape[0]

x_i = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,2]) # None x 2                        
y_i = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,1]) # None x 1                       

W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([2,1]))  # 2 x 1 
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1]))  # 1 x 1 

h = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x_i,W)+b)

cost = tf.reduce_sum(tf.add(tf.multiply(y_i,tf.log(h)),tf.multiply(1-
y_i,tf.log(1-h)))) / -m
```

i tried to use simple logistic cost function.it got returned 'NaN'.i thought my cost function is totally garbarage,got used tensorflow's example's cost function:

```
 cost = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(y_i*tf.log(h), reduction_indices=1))
```

but it didn't worked as well.

```
initializer= tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cost)

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)

    print("cost: ", sess.run(cost, feed_dict={x_i:training_X, 
    y_i:training_Y}), "w: ", sess.run(W),"b: ", sess.run(b))
```

Comment: What does "I've got unlabeled output data as {1,0}" mean, please?

Comment: it didn't one hot decoded.Just an binary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function `tf.nn.softmax` expects the number of logits (last dimension) to be equal the number of classes (2 in your case {1,0}). since the last dimension in your case is 1, softmax will always return 1 (the probability of being in the only available class is always 1 since no other class exists). therefore `h` is a tensor filled with 1's and `tf.log(1-h)` will return negative infinity. Infinity multiplied by zero (`1-y_i` in some rows) returns NaN.

You should replace `tf.nn.softmax` with `tf.nn.sigmoid`.

A possible fix is:

```
h = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.matmul(x_i,W)+b)
cost = tf.reduce_sum(tf.add(tf.multiply(y_i,tf.log(h)),tf.multiply(1-
y_i,tf.log(1-h)))) / -m
```

or better, you can use [tf.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits)
in that case, it should be done as follows:

```
h = tf.matmul(x_i,W)+b
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y_i, logits=h))
```

this function is more numerically stable than using `tf.nn.sigmoid` followed by the cross_entropy function which can return a NaN if `tf.nn.sigmoid` gets near 0 or 1 due to the imprecision of `float32`.

Comment: thank you!!
it has been solved by you.i hope that answer would be helpful to who faced same problem.